# Live Video Encryption in Java

Tags: java, video, encryption, live

I want to make a java project on streaming video encryption. Where i will use two PCs 1 act like a media server and other act like a client. So a video file (example.avi) in server pc can be view by client pc.

I already worked with sockets and can send files over a LAN. But here my question is ->
I want to send the encrypted video Stream to the client PC and the Client then display the video.

The process is like:

- Client request a video file
- Server open the video file (in text mode or something else) and start encrypting and sending to client.
- Now client start receving and decrypting the data.
- And display the decrypted data as video in details Server
- Connected to client
- Open the video file
- While Not EOF
- Read file content block
- Encrypt it
- Send encrypted block to the client
- End While Client
- Connected to server
- While True(Or something like that)
- Store the received encrypted data
- Decrypt it
- Display it as video
- End While

I do not need any source code for that. I just want to know that from where i can start this project. Any suggesstion will
   be helpful for me.

- Can connect two pc
- Can read files
- Can encrypt
- Can send data over LAN
- Can decrypt it

But how can i use the decrypted data and display it as video?

Comment: Not a good stackoverflow question. Please read the site FAQ.

Comment: First of all, you have to read FAQ & How to Ask http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Comment: What bad about this question?

Comment: @TanmayMajumder It's not actually about programming, it would be better for security.stackoverflow.com, but only if it hasn't been asked - in this case 1000 times - before.

Comment: If you can already send, encrypt, receive and decrypt the data, but you do not know how to display it... how is this question different from "I do not know how to display video in Java"? Why insist on the part you know how to do already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel here, because there is already a standardized technology to encrypt communication over TCP/IP: [Transport Layer Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Check out the classes [SSLSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html), [SSLServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocket.html), [SSLSocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) and [SSLServerSocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocketFactory.html). They behave just like the normal Socket classes (they extend them, so you don't even have to change the type), but they encrypt the data under the hood and decrypt it transparently when received without you having to do much.

Comment: Ok i understand. but how can i display the received data as video?

Comment: ..."Store the received encrypted data"..."Decrypt it"... That doesn't doesn't smell like transport layer security to me.

Comment: @TanmayMajumder sorry, but GUI programming in Java is not my area of expertise. Tht's one of the reasons why your question got closed - it is too overly broad and encompasses too many topics to give  a good answer. You should ask a new question about how to display a video stream in java (mention what gui framework you are using)